# Issue with Magento 2 upgrade from Magento 2.0.7 to Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento, magento2

I tried to upgrade the Magento 2 application from **2.0.7 & 2.1.2**, but it is showing a installation error during **composer update** command.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                           Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires composer/composer 1.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I have also applied the MDVA-532 patch. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can the following commands to update Magento 2.0.7 to Magento 2.1.2.

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
2. composer update
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you have a problem with your minimum-stability.

Try to write and edit the following in your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.2",
..... your other requiered stuff...
},
```

.... your other code for this file ....

and than:

```
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    }
```

After that, try the console commands like in the post before from [Abhinav Kumar Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40603929/6735106).

I edit the commands so they will work better in my opinion:

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.2 --no-update
2. composer update
3. bin/magento cache:clean
4. bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US
6. -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
7. bin/magento index:reindex
8. bin/magento cache:clean